# How to install to /usr/bin directory?

Tags: linux

New to using Linux and trying to install software called PrinceXML in the /usr/bin directory.

I've logged in as the root user, used wget to download the package, ran tar and followed the steps to install. When asked I then chose default install directory (/usr/local). I tried again specifying /usr/bin/

When I try to access it via the PHP wrapper I get a blank screen, which I'm fairly certain is because the software is installed in the wrong location.

Any guidance as to how to install into the /usr/bin directory would be greatly appreciated.

This is the call from the wrapper:

```
  $prince = new Prince('/usr/bin/prince');
```

Answer (score 2):

You specified `/usr/bin` as the prefix, rather than simply `/usr`. Probably your program is now distributed across `/usr/bin/lib`, `/usr/bin/share`, `/usr/bin/bin` etc.

You really shouldn't mess around with `/usr/bin`, your package manager manages this directory. Try to incrementally uninstall your software and reconfigure it again with `/usr/local` or `/opt/prince` as the install directory. Then adapt the wrapper to call the correct binary.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you specify `/usr` instead of `/usr/local` if you wanted it in `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`?

Where is it installed?  You can use the `which` command to find out where it is in your path.  Does your PHP program need to specify an absolute path, or can it execute it with just the app name?

```
$prince = new Prince('prince');
```

Comment: Makes sense. From Plesk it looks like the files are located in usr/local/lib/prince/ -- what's strange is when I change the directory in the PHP same issue. I'm going to look into the which command.